# RLinkedin Connectivity Error

Tags: r, linkedin-api

I am trying to use the Rlinkedin package to establish a connection to Linkedin.
I have followed the instructions in Rlinkedin package and r-bloggers link.

My code snippet looks like this (keys are hidden while posting):

```
library(Rlinkedin)
app_name <- "XXXX"
consumer_key <- "XXXX"
consumer_secret <- "XXXX"
in.auth <- inOAuth(app_name, consumer_key, consumer_secret)
my.connections <- getMyConnections(in.auth)
```

I have authenticated it through a browser, and my linkedin application page shows connections in the statistics.
However I get an error message as follows:

```
Error in UseMethod("xpathApply") : 
  no applicable method for 'xpathApply' applied to an object of class "c('xml_document', 'xml_node')"
```

Additionally running:
`getCompany(token=in.auth, universal_name="Facebook")`

Results in error:

```
Error in if (!is.na(q.content[["number(//error/status)"]] == 404)) { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

I tried using [the package from github](https://github.com/mpiccirilli/Rlinkedin) as well, but the same issue occurs.

Comment: I don't think this is supported anymore. LinkedIn changed the rules about its API a while back.

Answer (score 2):

They changed the rules about the API last May. You have to have a full partnership arraignment through your company to use the functions in that package.

I ran this package with elevated but non-partner privileges after contacting LinkedIn's developer program last year and even then the amount of stuff you could query was trivial and limited to your own profile.

> On May 12th 2015 LinkedIn changed the availability for most of their
>   API endpoints. In order to gain full access to the API, you must apply
>   to their Partnership Program. You can find detailed information
>   regarding what endpoints are still openly available in their
>   Transition Guide.
>
> Regarding this R package, the following lists cover which functions
>   are and are not available for non-partners. If I gain access to their
>   partnership program I will update the package accordingly.

As you can see from the quote above (taken from the package's GitHub page), even the package's author doesn't have partner access.

Comment: And just FYI -- I have tried to reach out to LinkedIn a number of times attempting to get access simply so I can keep the package up-to-date, but I have yet to receive a response.  I'm hoping that with Microsoft's acquisition of Revo they'll be a bit friendlier to the open source community  :)